# Loop through XML file and display only chosen node

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I am retrieving an online XML file and I want to loop through the file and only use the contents of the `Node` 'name'. Any idea how I should to it?

This is my XML-file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data><set name='Cuba Libre 43' id='10'>
<name>Cuba Libre 43</name>
<howto>Fill a highball glass half full with ice cubes. Add 3 cl rum, 3 cl of licor and 12 cl of cola, a few drops of squeezed lime and stir. Put a slice of lemon on the rim to finish.</howto>
<ingredient category='0'>Licor 43</ingredient>
<ingredient category='2'>Dark Rum</ingredient>
<ingredient category='0'>Cola</ingredient>
<ingredient category='0'>Ice cubes</ingredient>
<ingredient category='0'>Lemon wedge</ingredient>
<ingredient category='0'>Drops of squeezed lime</ingredient>
</set><set name='Blanco 43' id='11'>
<name>Blanco 43</name>
<howto>Put some ice cubes in the glass. Then add one part liqor and then 3 parts of milk.</howto>
<ingredient category='0'>Licor 43</ingredient>
<ingredient category='0'>Cold milk</ingredient>
<ingredient category='0'>Ice cubes</ingredient>
</set><set name='Dreamsicle' id='12'>
<name>Dreamsicle</name>
<howto>Put some ice cubes in a glass. Then add 1 part liqor, 2 parts milk and 2 part orange juice.</howto>
<ingredient category='0'>Licor 43</ingredient>
<ingredient category='0'>Milk</ingredient>
<ingredient category='0'>Orange juice</ingredient>
<ingredient category='0'>Ice cubes</ingredient>
</set><set name='Don Juan' id='13'>
<name>Don Juan</name>
<howto>Put some ice cubes in the glass. Then add 1 part licor and 3 parts orange juice.</howto>
<ingredient category='0'>Licor 43</ingredient>
<ingredient category='0'>Orange juice</ingredient>
<ingredient category='0'>Ice cubes</ingredient>
</set></data>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy with [Linq To Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688087.aspx).

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

var names = xDoc.Descendants("name").Select(n => n.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without LINQ/XMLDocument:

```
XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
while (rdr.Read())
{
    if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
       if (rdr.LocalName.Equals("name"))
       {
           Console.WriteLine(rdr.Value);
       }
    }
 }
```